# .htaccess blacklist from text file and redirect

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, blacklist

I have a site where I want to redirect incoming requests only if they **don't** appear in a blacklist file. I'd like to store the file outside the public html directory so it would be something like `var/www/blacklists/example.com.blacklist` and the content would look like

```
hello
about
contact
portfolio
```

If my site is `example.com` and the user visits `https://example.com/goodbye`, as long as "goodbye" **isn't** on the blacklist, it will redirect to `https://somethingelse.com/goodbye`.

If the user visits `https://example.com/hello` and "hello" **is** on the blacklist, it would resolve normally.

Also, all requests that resolve normally need to force ssl. `example.com/hello` or `http://example.com/hello` should be rewritten as `https://example.com/hello`

Thanks,
Howie

Comment: Do you have control over Apache server config?

Comment: Yes. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a text file in any path outside your `DocumentRoot`. Each line should contain 2 columns separated by a single space. 1st column should have your blacklisted path vale and 2nd column should have value `1`. Example below:

   ```
   cat /tmp/blacklist.txt

   hello 1
   about 1
   contact 1
   portfolio 1
   ```
2. Then inside the `httpd.conf` insert a new `RewriteMap` line as this:

   ```
   # First, we configure the "default" to be a very restrictive set of
   # features.
   <Directory />
        # Existing directives here
        # followed by this RewriteMap
        RewriteMap blacklist "txt:/tmp/blacklist.txt"
   </Directory>
   ```
3. Restart apache server
4. Finally, inside your site root .htaccess have these rules:

   ```
   RewriteEngine On

   RewriteCond ${blacklist:$0} !=1
   RewriteRule .+ https://somethingelse.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=302]

   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
   RewriteCond ${blacklist:$0} =1
   RewriteRule .+ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=302]
   ```